# What does the accounting term consolidated joint venture mean?

Tags: united-states, accounting

I live in the United States of America and I invest in public companies.

If firm A and firm B have a joint venture. Call this joint venture C. Assume each firm owns 50% of C. Firm A considers it a consolidated joint venture. Does this mean that firm A can count 50% of firm's C assets on its balance sheet? Does it mean it can count 50% of firm C's revenue as its own. I believe the answer is yes to both but I would like somebody more knowledgeable in accounting to confirm this.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: It seems so. https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/consolidated-joint-venture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consolidated means that the assets (and liabilities, revenue, expenses, etc.) are *consolidated* into the owning company's balance sheet and other financial statements.